# Upgrade Secure Store application from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, secure-store

I am trying to upgrade Secure Store service application from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 using powershall command following Tech net article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719(v=office.16).aspx

But it's failed and in log file getting below error:

VERSION LOG (GET): Upgrade object too new.  Current versions: (build version = 15.0.4923.1000, schema version = 15.0.3.0). Target versions: (build version = 16.0.4405.1000, schema version = 15.0.2.0).

Farm details:

SharePoint 2013+SP1+May 2017 CU

SharePoint 2016+May 2017 CU

Please guide me.

Comment: This is likely a bug. I'll see if I can reproduce it and report it to the correct folks.

Comment: It's definitely a bug. I've sent it off to the appropriate individuals. That said, consider opening a PSS case for additional reporting.

Comment: I get the same thing.  Upgrading from SharePoint 2013 w/ May 2017 CU to SharePoint 2016 w/ Sept 2017 CU.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2017 CU (Feature Pack 2), this issue has not been resolved.  It appears that the Secure Store schema version was incremented with the SP 2013 May 2017 CU to 15.0.3.0 but SharePoint 2016 RTM to latest CU use 15.0.2.0.

Though editing the databases is not supported, I was able to upgrade the Secure Store DB by editing the Versions table row that contained 15.0.3.0 and changed it to 15.0.2.0.  After following the steps to upgrade the Secure Store service (link below), the PowerShell commands finish with no errors and SharePoint 2016 reports the database upgrade status for the Secure Store DB as "no action required".

[https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719(v=office.16).aspx#Upgrade the Secure Store service application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719(v=office.16).aspx#Upgrade%20the%20Secure%20Store%20service%20application)

This issue is also being discussed on TechNet:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5eca6e5b-ffdd-4bc4-a841-b1b3d63bc304/upgrade-secure-store-application-from-sharepoint-2013-to-sharepoint-2016?forum=SP2016